# How to speed up construction phase whilst having an trivial overlapping constraint

Tags: optaplanner

We're are trying to put together a proof of concept planning constraints solver using OptaPlanner. However the construction phase seems slow for even a trivial set of constraints i.e. assign to one User with no overlapping Tasks for that User.

**Problem overview:**

We are assigning Tasks to Users
Only one Task can be assigned to User
The Tasks can be variable length: 1-16 hours
Users can only do one Task at a time
Users have 8 hours per day
We are using the Time Grain pattern - 1 grain = 1 hour.
See constraints configuration below.

This works fine (returns in a 20 seconds) for a small number of Users and Tasks e.g. 30 Users / 1000 Tasks but when we  start scaling up the performance rapidly drops off. Simply increasing the number of Users without increasing the number of Tasks (300 Users / 1000 Tasks) increases the solve time to 120 seconds.

But we hope to scale up to 300 Users / 10000 Tasks and incorporate much more elaborate constraints.

Is there a way to optimise the constraints/configuration?

```
Constraint constraint1 = constraintFactory.forEach(Task.class)
                            .filter(st -> st.getUser() == null)
                            .penalize("Assign Task", HardSoftLongScore.ONE_HARD);

Constraint constraint2 = constraintFactory.forEach(Task.class)
                            .filter(st -> st.getStartDate() == null)
                            .penalize("Assign Start Date", HardSoftLongScore.ONE_HARD);      

Constraint constraint3 = constraintFactory
                            .forEachUniquePair(Task.class,
                                                equal(Task::getUser), 
                                                overlapping(st -> st.getStartDate().getId(), 
                                                                st -> st.getStartDate().getId() + st.getDurationInHours()))
                            .penalizeLong("Crew conflict", HardSoftLongScore.ONE_HARD,
                            (st1, st2) -> {
                                int x1 = st1.getStartDate().getId() > st2.getStartDate().getId() ? st1.getStartDate().getId(): st2.getStartDate().getId();
                                int x2 = st1.getStartDate().getId() + st1.getDurationInHours()  < st2.getStartDate().getId() + st2.getDurationInHours() ? 
                                            st1.getStartDate().getId() + st1.getDurationInHours(): st2.getStartDate().getId() + + st2.getDurationInHours();
                                
                                return Math.abs(x2-x1);
                                
                            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`constraint1` and `constraint2` seem redundant to me. The Construction Heuristic phase will initialize all planning variables (automatically, without being penalized for not doing so) and Local Search will never set a planning variable to `null` (unless you're optimizing an over-constrained problem).

You should be able to remove `constraint1` and `constraint2` without impact on the solution quality.

Other than that, it seems you have two planning variables (`Task.user` and `Task.startDate`). By default, in each CH step, both variables of a selected entity are initialized "together". That means OptaPlanner looks for the best initial pair of values for that entity in the Cartesian product of all users and all time grains. This scales poorly.

See the [Scaling construction heuristics](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/construction-heuristics/construction-heuristics.html#scalingConstructionHeuristics) chapter to learn how to change that default behavior and for other ways how to make Construction Heuristic algorithms scale better.

Comment: Thanks. I found a huge improvement using a changeMoveSelector for each variable along with selectionOrder RANDOM for the User variable. I guess this is because if they are selected in order the same users get selected over and over again?

Comment: I don't think that's the reason. A single user is being selected repeatedly in each CH step in both cases (with or without Cartesian product). Let's say you have 1000 tasks, 300 users and 40 time grains. With the Cartesian product (default), CH takes 1000 steps, evaluating 12,000 possible moves in each step (12 million moves in total). With the sequential approach, there is 2000 CH steps but half of them has only 300 moves to try and the other half only 40 moves. That is 300k + 40k = 340k moves.

Comment: RANDOM does seem a lot faster i.e. 7 secs. If I comment out the selectionOrder from the User changeMoveSelector it takes a lot longer >10min with no end. Here is the config I'm using:

<constructionHeuristic>
    <changeMoveSelector>
      <selectionOrder>RANDOM</selectionOrder>
      <selectedCountLimit>300</selectedCountLimit>
      <valueSelector variableName="user"/>
    </changeMoveSelector>
    <changeMoveSelector>
      <valueSelector variableName="startDate"/>
    </changeMoveSelector>
  </constructionHeuristic>