# OptaPlanner optimizing Construction Heuristic phase for @PlanningEntity with 2 or more @PlanningVariable in java

Tags: java, optaplanner

I need to schedule tasks for employees. My approach works good enough for small number of workers and tasks (default). I read that I need to change construction heuristic scaling so I tried answer from  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70666268/how-to-speed-up-construction-phase-whilst-having-an-trivial-overlapping-constrai) stackoverflow answer and from [this](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/construction-heuristics/construction-heuristics.html#scalingConstructionHeuristics) part of documentation. It did not work, then I tried approach from [this](https://stackoverflow.com) blog, but it still did not work. I just want to point out that I did the implementation in Java because that is requirement of my project.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/jova5/opta-planner-job-schdule) to my github repo, where you will have an insight into the bigger picture of my solution.

I think that my first approach is the closest to answer and that solution to my problem lies in my constraint provider, but I am bagging my had for a long time and it seems that I am only further away from answer.

So this is my first approach to solving this problem.

```
...

    ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig phaseConfig = new ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig();
    ChangeMoveSelectorConfig changeMoveSelectorConfig = new ChangeMoveSelectorConfig();
    ValueSelectorConfig valueSelectorConfig = new ValueSelectorConfig();
    valueSelectorConfig.setVariableName("employee");
    changeMoveSelectorConfig.setValueSelectorConfig(valueSelectorConfig);
    ChangeMoveSelectorConfig changeMoveSelectorConfig1 = new ChangeMoveSelectorConfig();
    ValueSelectorConfig valueSelectorConfig1 = new ValueSelectorConfig();
    valueSelectorConfig1.setVariableName("startTime");
    changeMoveSelectorConfig1.setValueSelectorConfig(valueSelectorConfig1);
    phaseConfig.setMoveSelectorConfigList(Arrays.asList(changeMoveSelectorConfig,changeMoveSelectorConfig1));

    SolverConfig solverConfig = new SolverConfig().withPhaseList(List.of(phaseConfig));

...
```

And this is log that I got when debugging.

```
Solving started: time spent (43), best score (0hard/0medium/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0).
CH step (0), time spent (64), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_0 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (1), time spent (72), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_0 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (2), time spent (73), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_1 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (3), time spent (74), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_1 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (4), time spent (74), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_2 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (5), time spent (76), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_2 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (6), time spent (76), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_3 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (7), time spent (77), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_3 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (8), time spent (77), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_4 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (9), time spent (78), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_4 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (10), time spent (79), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_5 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (11), time spent (80), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_5 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (12), time spent (80), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_6 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (13), time spent (81), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_6 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (14), time spent (81), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_7 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (15), time spent (82), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_7 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (16), time spent (82), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_8 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (17), time spent (84), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_8 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (18), time spent (84), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_9 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (19), time spent (85), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_9 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (20), time spent (85), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_10 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (21), time spent (86), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_10 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (22), time spent (86), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_11 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (23), time spent (88), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_11 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (24), time spent (88), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_12 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (25), time spent (90), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_12 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (26), time spent (91), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_13 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (27), time spent (92), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_13 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (28), time spent (92), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_14 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (29), time spent (93), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_14 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (30), time spent (93), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_15 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (31), time spent (94), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_15 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (32), time spent (95), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_16 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (33), time spent (96), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_16 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (34), time spent (96), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_17 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (35), time spent (97), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_17 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (36), time spent (97), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_18 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (37), time spent (98), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_18 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (38), time spent (99), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_19 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (39), time spent (100), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_19 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (40), time spent (100), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_20 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (41), time spent (101), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_20 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (42), time spent (102), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_21 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (43), time spent (103), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_21 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (44), time spent (103), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_22 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (45), time spent (104), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_22 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (46), time spent (105), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_23 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (47), time spent (106), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_23 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (48), time spent (106), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_24 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (49), time spent (107), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_24 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (50), time spent (107), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_25 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (51), time spent (109), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_25 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (52), time spent (109), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_26 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (53), time spent (111), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_26 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (54), time spent (111), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_27 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (55), time spent (113), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_27 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (56), time spent (113), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_28 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (57), time spent (114), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_28 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (58), time spent (115), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_29 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (59), time spent (116), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_29 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (60), time spent (116), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_30 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (61), time spent (118), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_30 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (62), time spent (118), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_31 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (63), time spent (119), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_31 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (64), time spent (119), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_32 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (65), time spent (120), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_32 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (66), time spent (120), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_33 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (67), time spent (121), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_33 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (68), time spent (121), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_34 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (69), time spent (122), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_34 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (70), time spent (123), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_35 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (71), time spent (124), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_35 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (72), time spent (124), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_36 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (73), time spent (125), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_36 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (74), time spent (125), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_37 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (75), time spent (126), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_37 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (76), time spent (126), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_38 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (77), time spent (127), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_38 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (78), time spent (128), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_39 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (79), time spent (128), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_39 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (80), time spent (128), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (6), picked move (Task_40 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
CH step (81), time spent (129), score (0hard/0medium/0soft), selected move count (541), picked move (Task_40 Employee: null Start Time: null {null -> null}).
Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (130), best score (0hard/0medium/0soft), score calculation speed (291272/sec), step total (82).
Solving ended: time spent (130), best score (0hard/0medium/0soft), score calculation speed (172530/sec), phase total (1), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE).
```

As you can see construction heuristic phase iterated through all my tasks and tried to assign some value, but all value remain null. At the end I will provide my ConstructionProvider.

Second approach:

```
...

    ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig phaseConfig = new ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig();
    QueuedEntityPlacerConfig queuedEntityPlacerConfig = new QueuedEntityPlacerConfig();
    EntitySelectorConfig entitySelectorConfig = new EntitySelectorConfig();
    entitySelectorConfig.setCacheType(SelectionCacheType.PHASE);
    entitySelectorConfig.setEntityClass(Task.class);

    ChangeMoveSelectorConfig changeMoveSelectorConfig = new ChangeMoveSelectorConfig();
    changeMoveSelectorConfig.setEntitySelectorConfig(entitySelectorConfig);
    ValueSelectorConfig valueSelectorConfig = new ValueSelectorConfig();
    valueSelectorConfig.setVariableName("employee");
    changeMoveSelectorConfig.setValueSelectorConfig(valueSelectorConfig);

    ChangeMoveSelectorConfig changeMoveSelectorConfig2 = new ChangeMoveSelectorConfig();
    changeMoveSelectorConfig2.setEntitySelectorConfig(entitySelectorConfig);
    ValueSelectorConfig valueSelectorConfig2 = new ValueSelectorConfig();
    valueSelectorConfig2.setVariableName("startTime");
    changeMoveSelectorConfig2.setValueSelectorConfig(valueSelectorConfig);

    queuedEntityPlacerConfig.setEntitySelectorConfig(entitySelectorConfig);
    queuedEntityPlacerConfig.setMoveSelectorConfigList(Arrays.asList(changeMoveSelectorConfig, changeMoveSelectorConfig2));
    phaseConfig.setEntityPlacerConfig(queuedEntityPlacerConfig);

    SolverConfig solverConfig = new SolverConfig().withPhaseList(List.of(phaseConfig));

...
```

And third approach:

```
...

    ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig phaseConfig = new ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig();
    QueuedEntityPlacerConfig queuedEntityPlacerConfig = new QueuedEntityPlacerConfig();
    EntitySelectorConfig entitySelectorConfig = new EntitySelectorConfig();
    entitySelectorConfig.setCacheType(SelectionCacheType.PHASE);
    entitySelectorConfig.setEntityClass(Task.class);

    ChangeMoveSelectorConfig changeMoveSelectorConfig = new ChangeMoveSelectorConfig();
    changeMoveSelectorConfig.setEntitySelectorConfig(entitySelectorConfig);
    ValueSelectorConfig valueSelectorConfig = new ValueSelectorConfig();
    valueSelectorConfig.setVariableName("employee");
    changeMoveSelectorConfig.setValueSelectorConfig(valueSelectorConfig);

    queuedEntityPlacerConfig.setEntitySelectorConfig(entitySelectorConfig);
    queuedEntityPlacerConfig.setMoveSelectorConfigList(List.of(changeMoveSelectorConfig));
    phaseConfig.setEntityPlacerConfig(queuedEntityPlacerConfig);

    ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig phaseConfig2 = new ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig();
    QueuedEntityPlacerConfig queuedEntityPlacerConfig2 = new QueuedEntityPlacerConfig();

    ChangeMoveSelectorConfig changeMoveSelectorConfig2 = new ChangeMoveSelectorConfig();
    changeMoveSelectorConfig2.setEntitySelectorConfig(entitySelectorConfig);
    ValueSelectorConfig valueSelectorConfig2 = new ValueSelectorConfig();
    valueSelectorConfig2.setVariableName("startTime");
    changeMoveSelectorConfig2.setValueSelectorConfig(valueSelectorConfig);

    queuedEntityPlacerConfig2.setEntitySelectorConfig(entitySelectorConfig);
    queuedEntityPlacerConfig2.setMoveSelectorConfigList(List.of(changeMoveSelectorConfig2));
    phaseConfig2.setEntityPlacerConfig(queuedEntityPlacerConfig2);

    SolverConfig solverConfig = new SolverConfig().withPhaseList(Arrays.asList(phaseConfig, phaseConfig2));

...
```

Log for second ant third approach are identical and it will be available in github repo [here](https://github.com/jova5/opta-planner-job-schdule).

As you can see, in second and third approach constraint provider phase does not even iterate through my tasks.

And this is ConstraintProvider:

```
public class JobScheduleConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {
    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[]{
                noMoreTaskThanWorkingMinutes(constraintFactory),
                everyTaskShouldBeAssigned(constraintFactory),
                everyTaskShouldBeAssignedToEmployeeWithAdequateSkill(constraintFactory),
                tasksDontOverlap(constraintFactory),
                everyTaskShouldBeInitialized(constraintFactory),
                everyTaskShouldBeInitializedWithTime(constraintFactory),
        };
    }

    public Constraint noMoreTaskThanWorkingMinutes(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Employee.class)
                                .filter(employee -> employee.getSumMinutesOfAssignedTasks() >
                                                    employee.getWorkingMinutes())
                                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                                .asConstraint("noMoreTaskThanWorkingMinutes");
    }

    public Constraint everyTaskShouldBeAssigned(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Task.class)
                                .filter(task -> task.getEmployee() != null)
                                .reward(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_MEDIUM)
                                .asConstraint("everyTaskShouldBeAssigned");
    }

    public Constraint everyTaskShouldBeAssignedToEmployeeWithAdequateSkill(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Task.class)
                                .filter(task -> {
                                    if (task.getEmployee() == null) {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    return !task.getEmployee().getSkills().contains(task.getSkillRequired());
                                })
                                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                                .asConstraint("everyTaskShouldBeAssignedToEmployeeWithAdequateSkill");
    }

    public Constraint everyTaskShouldBeInitialized(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Task.class)
                                .filter(task -> task.getEmployee() == null)
                                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_MEDIUM)
                                .asConstraint("everyTaskShouldBeInitialized");
    }

    public Constraint everyTaskShouldBeInitializedWithTime(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Task.class)
                                .filter(task -> task.getStartTime() == null)
                                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_MEDIUM)
                                .asConstraint("everyTaskShouldBeInitializedWithTime");
    }

    public Constraint tasksDontOverlap(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Employee.class)
                                .filter(Employee::checkIfTasksOverlap)
                                .penalize(HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
                                .asConstraint("tasksDontOverlap");
    }
}
```

I were expecting that all my tasks would be assigned in construction heuristic phase, but that was not the case. Default approach (Cartesian) does not scale well but it works an it assigns all tasks, so I tried Sequential approach, but as you can see it does not work.

Thank you all for your time.

I am sorry for such a long question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem most likely lies in nullable planning variables. Your planning variables can remain unassigned, and there is no penalty in your constraint provider to fix that. The solver is leaving them unassigned, as it has no incentive to do otherwise.

You have two options:

- Don't make the variables nullable. I'd recommend that, because your constraints make it clear that you want every variable assigned.
- Use `forEachIncludingNullVars(...)` instead of `forEach(...)`, which will include entities with null variables, which will finally make your constraints trigger on unassigned variables.